# link to full article if you click "... Read more " as.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

New to asp.net c#

currently on my frontpage of the website im working on i have the top 3 news articles from my database ordered by date, and after 110 characters it says ..Read more. which works.

this is the news box that i repeat out the latest 3 articles with on the front page.

```
 <div class="nyhed">

   <h3><%# Eval("nyhed_overskrift") %></h3>

   <p><%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nyhed_tekst"), 110)%><a href="#">...Læs mere</a></p>

   <span> Oprettet | <%# Eval("nyhed_dato") %></span>

 </div>
```

my code behind that stops the text after 110 characters.

```
 protected string CutText(object text, int length)
{
    if (DBNull.Value == text || text == null) return "";
    string txt = text.ToString();
    if (txt.Length <= length) return txt;
    return txt.Substring(0, length);
}
```

this is what i expected to be my full article site

```
<div class="nyheder">
     <h1><%# Eval("nyhed_overskrift") %></h1>
     <p><%# Eval("nyhed_tekst") %></p>
     <p> <%# Eval("nyhed_dato") %></p>
        </div>
 <div class="nyheder_img">
     <img src='prod_image/<%# Eval("nyhed_billeder") %> '/>
        </div>
```

my question:
when you click "...Read more" i want it to link to a page where you can read the full news article and only the article you clicked "...Read more" on and i dont know how i should link to it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your question is very vague, but you simply need to generate a URL in your read more link. I don't know your site structure, but you need to point each Read More to the appropriate full document. If the full document is at article.aspx?id=10 then you will have to generate that on the fly, I assume you can Eval the ID from the database. But then again, I don't know if you have a page that opens articles.

Comment: @Null you can post your comment as answer, please add a code snippet to clarify to OP what do you mean

Comment: href="#" to be replaced with the url to the news only page like href="/newsDetails.aspx?newsid="+newsid

Comment: thank you @Null that is what i am looking for. could you show an example on how you would do something like that?

Comment: Well this should be easy, but hold on I will write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is generate your URL on the fly as you bind the rest of the data. Usually in most websites there is a separate page, let's call it **article.aspx** (*it doesn't matter how it's called*) which is visualizing documents in your website.

So, while you bind the rest of your data around your ReadMore section, you have to modify the URL on the fly:

```
<p>
  <%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nyhed_tekst"), 110)%>
  <a href='/article.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ArticleId")%>'>...Læs mere</a> 
</p>
```

ArticleId will be the identificator of your article from the database, I called it this way because I have no idea how you named yours. When you are done with this you can proceed to creating the article.aspx page which will visualize the document.

Looking at article.aspx, you could add a property above the Page_Load method, that will hold the ArticleId that we passed for us:

```
public int ArticleId
{
     get
     {
         //Attempt to extract ArticleId from QueryString, return 0 if we can't;
         int articleId = 0;
         if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(), out articleId))
         {
            return articleId;
         }
         return articleId;
     }
 }
```

And then at the Page_Load you have to implement the logic for displaying the article and in this case making a check if the ArticleId is correct:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //If you need to check for postbacks do it here, removed for simplicity;
   if(ArticleId != 0)
   {
      //Your own logic here, pull from database and bind the data to your controls;
      LoadDocument();        
   }
}
```

The result is having each of your ReadMore sections pointing to a different article.aspx?id=**X** where **X** will be the identificator of the related document.

Comment: If you got more questions related to this post a comment.

Comment: i did what you said, although i personally used a repeater and a sql datasource instead of writing it in codebehind, page_Load.

Comment: Yeah, the implementation is personal. But if you are displaying one article I don't see a reason for repeater and declarative binding, up to you of course.

Comment: Well to be honest it was the only way i remembered how ;) i guess the other way was to write the sql in codebehind as you said.

Comment: Start learning Entity Framework, it's widely used and comfortable to use. Once you get a grasp on it you can read this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application it's for MVC but you can apply the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to send Id(Primary key) of your article to next page by using Session/queryString. Here is an example using query string:

```
<p><%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"nyhed_tekst"), 110)%><a href="NameOfYourSecondPage.aspx?id=<%#Eval("YourArticleId") %>">...Læs mere</a></p>
```

Once you did this you need to recieve id from query string on second page:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("id"));
            //---- Now here you can get your complete article by using id and display on page.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must have a webform called Artical.aspx then

```
<ifram><div style="border:1px solid blue; min-height:152px;">
<%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "artDescrption"), 300)%>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("~/Article.aspx?artid={0}",Eval("artid"))%>' runat="server">...ReadMore</asp:HyperLink></div></ifram>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not appear to be a complete answer. Are you sure you included everything you meant to?

Answer (score 0):

To add a link to the main content, simply add this line of code right below the streamlined text.

```
<a href='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id",  "details.aspx?id={0}"))%>'>See Details</a>
```

This code simply passes the ID of this blog as a query string to a page called details.aspx. Take the query parameter and query your database for the post associated with that ID.